# Changing the graph settings and data in the runtime

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a graph (2-axis graph of achartengine) loaded in a layout started when app is created

```
createData(); // is public void, creates data array for maChartView
setGraph();  // is public void, set tittles and font sizes, range of interests
mylayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);     
mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer);
```

and I have a button that when pressed, the graph initially showed must change to show another set of data, tittle and roi (means range of interest, value intervals in x-axis and y-axis)

```
public void reDraw(View view){
    createData2();
    setGraph2();
    mChartView.repaint(); //mChartView is public instance of GraphicalView
}
```

All the instances and variables involved in `createData()` and `setGraph()` methods are public. The application starts ok in the emulator and the first graph is shown well, but when I press the button, nothing happens :( , I don't know why.

Can anyone give me an insight? Thanks.

Adding more details and modifing createData2, now it just recalculates y-values.
The user can enter three parameters for a polynomial of grade two, depending on those values, the corresponding graph will change. After the user enter the parameters, he press a button which trigger this

```
    public void reDraw(View view){

    List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    //createData2() returns a new set of y-values depending on the user inputs
    values = createData2();
    setGraph2();
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = buildDataset(titles, x, values);
    GraphicalView mChartView;
    mylayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
    mylayout.addView(mChartView, params);
    mChartView.repaint();
    }
```

When I test the code it runs OK in the first time I enter the parameters, but nothing happens when I enter a second set of parameters. If I rotate the emulator and press the draw button, the new graph comes out! but this is not the idea, the idea is that the new graph is re draw just after the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it.
I am not adding new data to the series, I need to recalculate de y-values (the same x-vales array is not touched). The repaint method has no effect. I've simply recreate the chart but this line is fundamental in my method reDraw(view view)

```
    mylayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
```

to remove the previous draw and set the new one. Now it works nice :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are completely creating a new chart when you press the button. However, you should only modify the series of the existing chart and then call `repaint`.